# How to mock the window navigator object while unit testing angular code

Tags: angular, unit-testing, jasmine

I am using jasmine to write a unit test in angular. The method uses the the window.navigator property. The property is defined outside the method like below

```
declare var navigator: any;
navigator = window.navigator;
```

In the method to be tested the below code is present which is to be tested

```
let locale = navigator.language || navigator.userLanguage || navigator.browserLanguage;
```

The first condition `navigator.language` gets covered automatically while running the unit test. 
I want to cover all branches of this code ie, I want to cover all OR conditions while testing. How do I mock the navigator in unit test?

Comment: Please, have a look at this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46806185/jasmine-js-testing-spy-on-window-navigator-useragent).

Comment: A more specific link to the answer referred by Anand: https://stackoverflow.com/a/56625422/1094673

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I created a method to return the navigator instead of refering it directly and then mocked the same method in the spec file.

In the component.ts file-

```
// method that returns navigator object
public getNavigatorReference(): any {
    return navigator;
}

// method that uses the above method
private methodThatUsesNavigator(): void {
   let navigatorReference = this.getNavigatorReference();
   let locale = navigatorReference.language || navigatorReference.userLanguage || 
   navigatorReference.browserLanguage;
...
}
```

In the spec file -

```
Object.defineProperty(navigator, 'userLanguage', {
      get: function () { return 'en'; }
});
```

Comment: This is not the way to go, Angular encourages you to use the DI for exact this type of testing purposes

Answer (score 2):

I created a custom InjectionToken for it, which can easily be passed in via constructor in Service-tests:

---

**app/tokens/navigator.injection-token.ts**:

```js
import { InjectionToken } from '@angular/core';

export const NavigatorToken = new InjectionToken('navigator-token');
```

**app/app.module.ts**:

```js
import { NavigatorToken } from './tokens/navigator.injection-token.ts';

@NgModule({
  providers: [
    {
      provide: NavigatorToken,
      useValue: navigator,
    }
  ]
})
export class AppModule {}
```

**app/services/language-service.ts**:

```js
export class MyService {
  constructor(@Inject(NavigatorToken) private navigatorInstance: typeof navigator) {}

  get browserLanguage(): string {
    return this.navigatorInstance.language;
  }
}
```

Test:

```js
describe('MyService', () => {
  let service: MyService;

  beforeEach(() => {
    service = new MyService({ language: 'mock-lang' } as any);
  });

  it('should work', () => {
    expect(service.browserLanguage).toBe('mock-lang');
  });
});
```